# Using PHP to send SQL Query, keeps failing?

Tags: php, sql

This is my PHP code:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `reviews`(`Departed`, `Returned`, `Name`, `Review`) VALUES ($departed,$returned,$name,$message)";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);

    $review[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
```

The query fails to execute, but the string looks okay:

```
request "Could not execute SQL query" INSERT INTO `reviews`(`Departed`, `Returned`, `Name`, `Review`) VALUES (2015-08-01,2015-08-06,test,test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the input strings

```
... VALUES ('2015-08-01', '2015-08-06', 'test', 'test')
```

or way better use Prepared Statements that do that and more for you.

Comment: beat me to it.  UPVOTED

Comment: Normally you'd use that term if someone is a few seconds faster, not 15 minutes ;)

Comment: what a linear concept.  fyi: i opened the window (new tab) while approving / rejecting questions.  you had NOT yet answered.  i went back to verifying questions and returned.  tahnks for telling me it took me at least 15 minutes.  i really dont lose time keeping time that way.  try relative time, its pretty natural, actually.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR and DATE must be enclosed in quotes.  Only numbers may be stripped of quotes.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `reviews`(`Departed`, `Returned`, `Name`, `Review`) VALUES ('$departed','$returned','$name','$message')";
```